# Approximating $\pi$ with arctangent

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation

Use the fact that $\frac{\pi}{4} = \text{arctangent}(\frac{1}{2}) + \text{arctangent}(\frac{1}{3})$ to determine the number of terms summed to ensure an approximation to $\pi$ less than $10^{-3}$.

So far I've got

\begin{align*}
    \pi = 4\Bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{i+1}\frac{1}{2^{2i-1}(2i-1)} + \sum_{i=1}^{n} (-1)^{i+1}\frac{1}{3^{2i-1}(2i-1)}\Bigg)
\end{align*}

from the given identity. But I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What you've "got so far" is false; it's only true for sums to infinity. So the real story is $\pi = 4(\sum^n \ldots + E_1(n) + \sum^n \ldots + E_2(n))$, where $E_1(n)$ and $E_2(n)$ are the "error terms" for those two power series. What you need to do is find a value $n$ large enough that $|E_1(n)| + |E_2(n)| < 10^{-3}$. (You should ask yourself why I put in those absolute-value brackets, too). When you've found the error terms and tried to work with them, if you're still stuck, you can show your work by clicking "edit" below your question; then we can help further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the equality as:
\begin{array}{}
    \pi = 4\left[\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} (-1)^{i}\left(\frac{1}{2^{2i+1}(2i+1)} +\frac{1}{3^{2i+1}(2i+1)}\right)+\sum\limits_{i=n}^{\infty} (-1)^{i}\left(\frac{1}{2^{2i+1}(2i+1)} +\frac{1}{3^{2i+1}(2i+1)}\right)\right]
\end{array}
to obtain the inequality to be solved for $n$:
$$
\begin{array}{}
 4\left|\sum\limits_{i=n}^{\infty} (-1)^{i}\left(\frac{1}{2^{2i+1}(2i+1)} +\frac{1}{3^{2i+1}(2i+1)}\right)\right|<\epsilon=10^{-3}.\tag1
\end{array}$$

Observe now that the series (1) is alternating with monotonously decreasing terms, and [thus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) the absolute value of the series is less than that of its first term.

Comment: Solving that thing for $n$ seemed pretty tedious. I just plugged in values and got $n=4$. Does that seem correct?

Comment: @mXdX My initial answer was intended as a hint and I am really happy that you have completed the task. Your step is correct. I have added it now in the answer for certainity.

Answer (score 1):

The sums are alternating and the terms decreasing in absolute value. This implies that the error is lesser or equal to the first discarded term. The error summing up to $n$ is then lesser or equal to
$$
4\Bigl(\frac{1}{2^{2n+1}(2\,n+1)}+\frac{1}{3^{2n+1}(2\,n+1)}\Bigr).
$$
Now choose $n$ so that the above is $<10^{-3}$.

Comment: This is the result I got. From here, it seemed best to just try values for $n$. Looks like it's $n=4$, yes?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.